# Stream Filter memory usage

Tags: php, amazon-s3

PHP v7.4.16

I have a fairly basic stream filter (which extends php_user_filter), which I'm using to normalise CSV files as they're transferred to another destination (s3 bucket using the stream wrapper in this case).

Contents of filter() function:

```
 while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {

            // Replace any CRLF Windows line-endings with *nix \n
            $bucket->data = preg_replace('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R~', "\n", $bucket->data);

            $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($bucket->data, mb_detect_order(), true);
            $bucket->data = strtolower($encoding) != "utf-8"
                ? iconv($encoding, "utf-8//IGNORE", $bucket->data)
                : $bucket->data;

            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;

            // Send bucket to downstream brigade
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }

        // Return the code that indicates that the userspace filter returned buckets in $out
        return \PSFS_PASS_ON;
```

I can successfully use the filter like this:

```
 private function streamFileToS3($file_entity) {
        $source = fopen($file_entity->local_path, 'r');
        $dest = fopen($file_entity->s3_path, 'w');
        @\stream_filter_prepend($dest, 'csv', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
        $chunk_size = (10 * 1024 * 1024);
        while (!feof($source)) {
          
            $chunk = fread($source, $chunk_size);
            fwrite($dest, $chunk);
        }
        fclose($dest);
        fclose($source);
        return true;
    }
```

Now here's the important bit.

When appending the filter the to the file handle I'm **writing** to, the script uses the memory I'm expecting.

```
 @\stream_filter_prepend($dest, 'csv', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
```

But when I try to use the filter on the file handle I'm **reading** from:

```
 @\stream_filter_prepend($source, 'csv', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
```

The output of memory_get_usage() **increments by the size of the fread() chunk each iteration**.

Does anybody know why this is, and if there's any way around it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, I ran into this issue in a slightly different way, but still involving memory limitations. My solution was using this package: https://github.com/box/spout. you'll need a couple of extensions enabled and sadly you'll need to slightly modify your workflow.

Comment: Hi @Ballard , I'm not sure that will solve my particular use-case unfortunately, but thanks for mentioning, I hadn't come cross this library.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what differences you are expecting, because what i get from this so far is your internal buffers are being exhausted, you can try to flush out after each action to avoid memory leak maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more time spent investigating, I came across a couple of instances of other people running into similar problems:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78902
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79143

It seems there have been a couple of memory-leak issues present throughout PHP V7. Since my environment is using Docker, it was very straight forward to test some other versions to see if the issue persisted.

In my case, the issue was present when using:

- php:7.4.2-apache
- php:7.4.18-apache

But the problem appears to be solved when using

- php:8.0.5-apache

Hope this helps somebody else that might be banging their head against a wall with this one.